# Running Time of Nested Loops, When inner loop false,

Tags: performance, time, time-complexity, big-o

01.) Considering the growth time, When the inner loop of a nested loop is false, is its growth time O (n)?
ex:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){    
    for (int j=0; j>n; i++){
        //some code
    }
}
```

02.) Considering the growth time, When the inner loop of a nested loop has another array length variable as 'm', is its growth time O (n m)?
ex:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){    
    for (int j=0; j<m; i++){
        //some code
    }
}
```

3. What is the running time of the following code? (please explain with steps)

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {                  
   for (int j = 0; j > n; j++) {               
      for (int k = 0; k > n; k++) {            
         System.out.println("*");   
      }
   }
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "growth time" and  "loop is false"?

Comment: I think ```loop is false``` indicates that the conditional of the loop will always be ```false```, regardless of the input size. So we can simply ignore that loop. ```growth time``` indicates the ```time complexity``` I guess.

Comment: Did my solution help you @Anonymous?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, if it is absolutely clear that inner loop will not be executed due to the conditional's being `false` regardless of the input size, then time complexity will be `O(n)`.
2. Yes, a detailed analysis can be found below. However, I assume you incorrectly incremented `i` in your inner loop.

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){    
    for (int j=0; j<m; j++){   // j++
        //some code
    }
}
number of operations performed by inner loop in each iteration of outer loop : m
number of operations performed by outer loop : n
Total number of operations : n*m
Time complexity f(n) ∈ O(n*m)
```

If the code you posted is not incorrect, then the time complexity analyis:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){    
    for (int j=0; j<m; i++){
        //some code
    }
}
j=0 --> j<m  (i++)
If 0<m, then it is an infinite loop. It's pointless to make a time complexity analysis. 
If 0>=m, then inner loop is not going to be executed, therefore time complexity will be O(n).
```

3. Detailed analysis:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {           // n many times
   for (int j = 0; j > n; j++) {        // n many times       
      for (int k = 0; k > n; k++) {     // n many times         
         System.out.println("*");   
      }
   }
}
All of the loops are iterated n many times. Most-inner loop will perform n operations. Outer loop will perform n, which makes n*n. And most-outer loop will perform n operations, which makes n*n*n in total.
Time complexity f(n) ∈ O(n^3)
```